.net v8 MAUI: How to display an image at last tap location?
Using .net8 MAUI for iOS, I display an image in an iOS App. It has some "hot zones", which are invisible buttons. They will trigger some kind of action (e.g. raising the score).
I want to display a special kind of "mouse cursor" (I will use a .png for it) exactly where the user tapped.
I can display the cursor (png-image) anywhere I want using an AbsoluteLayout, using AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds. However, I do not manage to dynamically update this location in C#.
Any thoughts on this?
Cursor myCursor = new Cursor("custom.cur"); --> no success, requires Cursor Class.

I think you could simply use GestureRecognizers. I've tried it on android, but it should work on ios the same way:
xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ImageTap.MainPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            BackgroundColor="Blue" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1000,1000">
            <VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
        <Image x:Name="cursor" Source="cursor.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,128,128"></Image>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>

cs:
namespace ImageTap
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
        {
            Point? clickedPosition = e.GetPosition((View)sender);
            cursor.TranslationX = clickedPosition.Value.X;
            cursor.TranslationY = clickedPosition.Value.Y;
        }
    }
}


nice! it works perfectly on iOS as well! Thanks
